# Directory auto completion in bash scripts

Tags: autocomplete, bash-scripting

Bash scripting newbie here writing my first script to copy a directory of pictures from one place to another.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Moves picture directories
cp -R /path/to/pictures/$1 /home/myUser/Pictures/$2
chmod -R 777 /home/myUser/Pictures/
```

This works fine, but my `$1` variable can be a rather long string of date info, so if possible, I'd like to have it use the standard tab auto-completion.  Likewise for `$2`, because I have several sub-categories under pictures and it would be nice to be able to tab-complete them.

ex:  `my_script 2014-07-<tab>` would autocomplete to `my_script 2014-07-15` if that's the only directory that starts with that script.

Is there any way to accomplish this for custom scripts?  On Ubuntu 14.04 if it's of any consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing such things in *nix tools is to not hard code specific directories at all, but rather passing both paths in full to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Moves picture directories
cp -R -- "$1" "$2"
chmod -R 777 "$(dirname -- "$2")"
```

Two nice side effects:

- **Autocomplete works without any extra code.**
- The script works no matter where your picture directories are, even with relative paths.

If you *have* to autocomplete with a specific path prefix, you could try checking out the [bash_completion code](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git) and how they autocomplete paths.

Comment: While this is good advice - do you know of any way to perform autocomplete within the hard-coded directories?  The script is for someone else with not as solid of a grip on computers/directory structures so I'm hoping to make it as straightforward as possible.